# Watch battery issues

Tags: battery, apple-watch

I have a Series 3 Watch that is about 4 years old (purchased new). I have noticed that when I place it on the Apple charger, it dings, and the green charge symbol comes on as normal. After about 2 minutes, I hear the ding again and see the charge symbol come on. This will repeat if don't do anything. I have tried to keep tabs on the charging via my iPhone and will catch it **not** charging then the ding-charge symbol on the Watch. I have also tried a [Wireless Charger](https://store.boingboing.net/sales/apple-watch-wireless-charger-keychain?utm_source=StackCommerce%20Marketing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Shipping%20Confirmation) and it does the same thing.

After doing some online research, the suggestion was to reset the Watch. This has worked but after a few weeks, it will go back to the ding-charge bit again.

A new odd behavior has presented itself. While on the charger, the Watch will reboot itself a few times and then continue to charge.

Is the battery going out on the Watch or is there something I can do to stop this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't good diagnostic data (unlike a MacBook) that you can get out of the watch.  However, I sounds like the "full charge capacity" is now insanely low and it no longer holds a charge.  What will happen is your battery starts to charge (dings), it reaches full because the capacity is low, discharges quickly because it can't hold a charge anymore, then charge again (subsequent ding).  Wash, rinse, repeat.  What happens if you wear the watch?  How long before it runs out of juice?

Comment: It works just as it always has; the charge will last almost all day long.

Comment: Try a different MagSafe charger; a friend's perhaps.    It may be failing (low probability, but still possible)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have tried a second charger (though a [Wireless Charger](https://store.boingboing.net/sales/apple-watch-wireless-charger-keychain?utm_source=StackCommerce%20Marketing&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Shipping%20Confirmation))

Comment: Wow... I'm out of ideas on this one.  Normally, given the age, it would be the battery.  What if you were to try charging when it's around 50%?  I'm wondering if there's a failing cell at the end of the series where it only affects things at or near full charge.

Comment: It's at 40% right now. I will set it to charge and see what happens in the future and update then.

Comment: Cool.  Make note of the time it takes.  Then charge again when full(-ish).  Note the elapsed time as well.

Comment: @Allan From 40% to 100% took 1h 26m.

Comment: Did it ding repeatedly during that period?

Comment: No, the last time the dinging happened was about a week ago. I am just trying to find an answer/solution to it.

Comment: Let’s see if it starts when it’s close to or at full

Comment: @Allan I let the watch drop to 99% then put it back on the charger; it took about 30m to charge back to 100%. No dinging.